# Cup product structure on $\mathbb{R}P^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, projective-space

I don't understand a passage in my lecture notes. Here is the passage with my questions added in italics:

> $H^\ast(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ in degrees $1$ and $2$. Let $\gamma$ be the a generator of $H^1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. Let us compute $\gamma \cup \gamma$. Recall the presentation $\mathbb{R}P^2$ as a circle (*It should be "disk" and not "circle“, right?*) with the two halves of the boundary identified. We fix a base point $\ast$. Let $\ast_1$ be the constant $1$-simplex and $\ast_2$ the constant $2$-simplex at the base point $\ast$. Let $c$ be the $1$-simplex that is half the boundary of the disk, it is easy to see this is a generator for $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, \ast)$ and thus for $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. (*How do I see that $c$ is a generator for $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2, \ast)$?*). Lastly, let $s$ be the $2$-simplex that maps onto the disk homeomorphically, with boundary $2\gamma -\ast_1$. (*This should read "$2c-\ast_1$" and not "$2\gamma -\ast_1$"?*). It follows that $s-\ast_2$ is a generator of $H_2(\mathbb{R}P^2)$. (*Why does that follow?*).
> We then must have $\gamma(c)=1$ and $\gamma(\ast_1)=0$. (*$\gamma(\ast_1)=0$ follows from $\ast_1=\partial \ast_2$ and $\gamma(c)=1$ from $\gamma\neq 0$ and $c$ being a generator of $H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, correct?*). We therefore find $\gamma \cup \gamma (s)=1$ and $\gamma \cup \gamma (\ast_2)=0$. We still need to show that $\gamma\cup \gamma$ is not a coboundary (*Why is this not obvious?*).